# How to create a sharedaccesssignature URL for my blob file in Azure Data Lake Gen2 in csharp

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm using the [Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake) nuget package to write and append file on my Azure Storage account that is enabled for Data Lake Gen2 (including hierarchy).

However, I don't seem to find how to generate a SAS-url to access a specific blob, without authenticating a user.  Is it possible to have this done with the package, or should I fall back to REST operations for this?

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I just had to click through to the GitHub page and there's a good example of how to do this in the Unit tests.

I copied the permalink to the specific part here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/89955a90641742a2cdb0acd924f90d02b1be34ec/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L126

```cs
AccountSasBuilder sas = new AccountSasBuilder
{
    Protocol = SasProtocol.None,
    Services = AccountSasServices.Blobs,
    ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.All,
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    IPRange = new SasIPRange(IPAddress.None, IPAddress.None)
};
// Allow read access
sas.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.List);

// Create a SharedKeyCredential that we can use to sign the SAS token
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);

// Build a SAS URI
UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder(StorageAccountBlobUri);
sasUri.Query = sas.ToSasQueryParameters(credential).ToString();
```